# Automatically set the value column at creation time record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a table named '**Prices**'With
the following columns

```
id 
key 
amount 
status
```

I want the status column to be set automatically when the record is created, but in such a way that it first takes the ***amount***  column value of the previous row and with the column ***amount*** Compare the current record, if the current record is greater, set the **status*** column value to 0, otherwise 1.

Comment: `CONSTRAINTS` can't reference other rows, no. You *could* use a user defined scalar function, but this can perform poorly, and this also becomes more muddy if you are inserting 2 or more rows. What is the default value of amount when you `INSERT` 2 rows? Do you need to compare the values within the dataset you are inserting too? In truth, this would be logic better handled in a procedure that handles the `INSERT` statements.

Comment: If your column has dependency on another row's data then perhaps your design isn't too great. Such columns are better to calculate on the fly, using one of the many window functions available

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `id` column is an auto-incrementing integer and that you want to order the rows based on their key values, you could use the following SQL query to set the status column based on the conditions you mentioned

```
WITH previous_row AS (
  SELECT *,
         LAG(amount) OVER (ORDER BY key) AS previous_amount
  FROM table
)
UPDATE table
SET status = CASE
               WHEN amount > previous_amount THEN 0
               ELSE 1
             END
FROM previous_row
WHERE table.id = previous_row.id + 1;
```

the CTE was created to include the columns from the original table as well as an additional `previous_amount` column that contains the value of the amount column from the previous row, ordered by key. The `LAG` window function is used to retrieve the `previous row's` amount value.

if you can share the sample values or additional information about the table/data that would be helful to refine this answer.